# Checking with Array[index] multiple times vs setting it a variable and using it - JAVASCRIPT/NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance

I have a bunch of if statements and setting/adding different props into my array. My javascript code is like;

```
for(var key in animals){

if(animals[key].eyesColor == "blue"){

  animals[key].hairColor = "yellow"  
  ...

  ...

  } 
}
```

As I checked, I'm using 78 times animals[key].props
And my array probably contains more than 1000 items.

Should I set the animal[key] to a variable and then set back this variable to my sample array at the end of my code? In this way can I improve the performance?

```
for(var key in animals){

let animal = animals[key]

if(animal.eyesColor == "blue"){

  animal.hairColor = "yellow"

  ...
  ...
  }

animals[key] = animal

}
```

Comment: Seems like a simple thing to test, but using variables will make your code easier to read and easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting and modifying all these datas from websocket which I receive 20/30 requests per second. So it's kinda important for me to make sure.